# Issue with structure of data.frame for sunburstR plot

Tags: r, sunburst-diagram, htmlwidgets

Hello,

I created the dataframe below, based on the example in the sunburstR documentation.

```
                         Column Count 
 1:                      ACTIVE 68764
 2:                    INACTIVE 73599
 3:             ACTIVE-RESIDENT 68279
 4:          ACTIVE-NONRESIDENT   485
 5:           INACTIVE-RESIDENT 63378
 6:        INACTIVE-NONRESIDENT 10221
 7:       ACTIVE-RESIDENT-LATIN    55
 8:      ACTIVE-RESIDENT-CYRLIC 68224
 9:    ACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-LATIN   465
10:   ACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-CYRLIC    20
11:     INACTIVE-RESIDENT-LATIN   114
12:    INACTIVE-RESIDENT-CYRLIC 63264
13:  INACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-LATIN  7915
14: INACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-CYRLIC  2306
```

The first column is character, the second is integer.

However when I try to plot it, I get nothing.

```
sunburst(sunburst_data)
```

Any hints whats wrong with the structure of my dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Include only the leaf nodes in your data frame...

```
df <- read.table(text = '
Column Count 
ACTIVE-RESIDENT-LATIN    55
ACTIVE-RESIDENT-CYRLIC 68224
ACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-LATIN   465
ACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-CYRLIC    20
INACTIVE-RESIDENT-LATIN   114
INACTIVE-RESIDENT-CYRLIC 63264
INACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-LATIN  7915
INACTIVE-NONRESIDENT-CYRLIC  2306
')

library(sunburstR)
sunburst(df)
```